# How do I simplify $\frac{10}{(1+ 6\%)} + \frac{10}{(1+ 6\%)^2} +\frac{10}{(1+ 6\%)^3} +... +\frac{10}{(1+ 6\%)^\infty}$

Tags: finance, geometric-series

How do I simplify 
$\frac{10}{(1+ 6\%)} + 
\frac{10}{(1+ 6\%)^2} +
\frac{10}{(1+ 6\%)^3} +
... +
\frac{10}{(1+ 6\%)^\infty}$

So I get to $\frac{10}{6\%}$
?

What are the intermediary steps ?
What is the demonstration ?

Comment: Well, you can probably see that it's the sum of a geometric series, right? Do you know how to calculate the sum of a geometric series in general? The Wikipedia page can help you, for example.

Comment: Check for convergence of geometric series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$S_n = r + r^2 + ... + r^n$$
Multiply $S_n$ by $r$ and subtract both expresions:
$$S_n-S_nr=S_n(1-r)=r-r^{n+1}$$You will obtain 
$$S_n=\frac{r-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

Substitute $r=1/(1+0.06)$ and multiply this result by $10$. In the case that $n\to\infty$ it results that $r^{\infty}\to 0$, and you will simply have:
$$S_\infty = \frac{r}{1-r}=\frac{1}{1/r-1}=10\frac{1}{(1+0.06)-1)}$$